# Actionscript2.0, gotoandplay does not work

Tags: flash, actionscript

In my actionscript code gotoandplay is not working. I want to play another frame when my object touches wall101.

```
if (hitTest(_level0.wall101)==true)
{
   gotoAndPlay(3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be occurring in multiple places: either the condition itself, or what it is controlling.

Make the following change to your code:

```
if (hitTest(_level0.wall101)==true)
{
   trace("Hit occured");
   gotoAndPlay(3);
}
```

**If you see 'hit occured'** at the expected time in the Flash Professional 'output' tab (it should pop up if it's not already in view), then your issue is with the clip you are attempting to control the timeline of.

For the sake of example, I am assuming your code on the first frame of some-kind of movable MovieClip (which I will refer to as 'playerClip'). If so, the 'gotoAndPlay' command will control the timeline of playerClip.

**If you didn't see 'hit occured'**, then your condition isn't occuring. Are you sure the instance name of the wall object is `wall101`? Remembering that instance name, and the name of the object in the library are two completely different things...

If you wanted to control the main timeline (not the timeline of playerClip), then change the `gotoAndPlay(3)` to: `_root.gotoAndPlay(3)`

*Also, don't refer to _level0... you should refer to _root (which is the same thing unless you are dealing with nested SWF timelines, and I doubt you are), or better yet even the parent of the object you are adding the code to (_parent)*